# Diskspace 0 Bytes free

Tags: disk-usage

today I made some filecopies from external disk to my (boot)SSD. After some minutes  I found out, there is 0 Bytes free space left.

I asked google -> delete bi cache files -> so I deleted a few bigger files in the .cache directory... But there are 0 Bytes of free space....

I asked google -> delete old kernels -> so I deleted round about a dozen old kernels. ... But there are 0 Bytes free disk space.

So I tried to use BAOBAB to find the files ... and there is shown 9,5GB free disk space!!!

I don't want to reboot the system because I find some articles that the system don't let you login because of 0 Bytes free disk space.

I hope you can help me
R.

Comment: have you tried to permanently delete some files? I am having the same Issue, but i managed to delete files and free up some space by doing so permanently with Shift+del. I later found out, that the non-permanently deleted files were moved to the Trash folder at ~/.local/share/Trash/ but since there were 0B left the needed .trashinfo files couldn't be created and nothing showed up in Trash. I still have both wrong and conflicting free disk space and Dolphin claims in the properties of my SSD that over 130TB are used on my 1TB ssd...But at least now I have some free space.

Comment: I deleted permanently. In the trash bin are a few MB files But I found out, that timeshift made yesterday and today a backup on my boot-SSD and additional I found in the \var\log\journal a directory with 100 files (with 2,2GB). But there is still a difference between BAOBAB and the free space shown in nautilus...

Comment: File size is never consistent between applications.  They are only ever estimates.  (Imagine how slow your computer would be if it actually counted every byte of data just to display a number in the corner of your file manager).  I suggest that you STOP using the installed OS until you have cleared space.  If you really don't have room for your OS work, then you can damage your whole OS. Instead, boot from installation media (Try Ubuntu). I suggest downloading the `filelight` application in the live session to get a graphical pie-chart representation of the files and folders on your drives.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the discrepancy in free space in your case comes down to two things:

#### 1. Estimations

Most programs won't show you the real used space but an estimate.
Files might only be calculated to nearest block size, meaning a 1 byte file might show up as 4 KiB in one program and as 1 byte in another

#### 2. Reserved space for root

root needs some space to prevent things like an actually full disk (making the system unusable) and for anti-fragmentation strategies used by Linux file-systems.
You can read more about that on the [Ubuntu Help page on DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).
You should read the [Absolute Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).
This can cause a difference between the sum of used+unused space and the total capacity of your drive.